# ntopng update error on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

An attempting update of ntopng on ubuntu 16.04 LTS resulted in this annoying error during 'apt-get install ntopng' ( run as root )

Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ntopng 
Failed to execute operation: File Exists
dpkg: error processing package ntopng (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

I'd previously completely removed ntopng using commands -
apt-get purge --auto-remove ntopng
deleting any other files/directories in /etc that were left over such as the empty directories /etc/ntop, /etc/pfring, /etc/nprobe, /etc/cento and /etc/nbox.
performed a reboot 'shutdown -r now'
and checked no ntopng files were left hanging around using 
'dpkg -L ntopng'.

So all looked OK for a complete reinstall but this error fails the new installation. 
Anybody have any idea what file the error is referring to ?

UPDATE - digging around, I had libfakeroot file left over in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot which I trashed and started again - with same result.

Comment: have you tried `apt-get install -f` and then installing `ntopng`?

Comment: Just tried that after another complete deinstallation, clean up and reboot. I get the same error.

Comment: ok, now run `apt-get autoremove` and try again with the installation.

Comment: apt-get autoremove - gives same error

Comment: Try the following: 

   rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/ntopng*
   dpkg -P --force-all ntopng
   apt-get install -f
   apt-get install ntopng

Comment: Tried those commands Dimitar, the 'dpkg -P --force-all ntopng' returned message ntopng wasnt installed. Tried installation with same error at same place in execution.

Answer (score 2):

The command "systemctl disable ntopng" then reinstall worked for me